# How to add a redrive policy (dead-letter queue / DLQ) to a SNS subscription, with Ansible and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ansible, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

In an Ansible script I have:

```
- name: Subscribe lambda to SNS topic example1
  sns_topic:
    name: "example1-{{env_name}}"
    purge_subscriptions: no
    subscriptions:
      - endpoint: "arn:aws:lambda:{{ aws.region }}:{{ aws.account }}:function:{{repo_name}}-{{env_name}}"
        protocol: "lambda"
```

It works, and the result is that my lambda is subscribed to my SNS topic.

Now, I would want to add a DLQ to this subscription.
I already have a SQS and I want to state it as my DLQ.

So I rewrite my code like this:

```
- name: Subscribe lambda to SNS topic example1
  sns_topic:
    name: "example1-{{env_name}}"
    purge_subscriptions: no
    subscriptions:
      - endpoint: "arn:aws:lambda:{{ aws.region }}:{{ aws.account }}:function:{{repo_name}}-{{env_name}}"
        protocol: "lambda"
        redrive_policy:
          dead_letter_target_arn: "arn:aws:{{ aws.region }}:{{ aws.account }}:dlq-for-example1"
```

This does not work and I didn't find anything in Ansible or by googling...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing `sqs` between `arn:aws:{{aws.region}}` on the last line.

```
dead_letter_target_arn: "arn:aws:sqs:{{ aws.region }}:{{ aws.account }}:dlq-for-example1"
```

Comment: After many different attempts, no solution for this.
However, in the meanwhile, something changed so I added an SQS which receives messages from SNS. Therefore, I set the DLQ for SQS and it works (when the lambda after SQS does not process messages correctly).
Now this situation is quite robust.

Comment: If SQS is down, SNS won't be able to deliver notifications. So setting up DLQ for SNS may be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Subscription property that is embedded in the SNS Topic only has two properties:  Endpoint and Protocol (See [Subscription Property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-subscription.html)).

For more advanced settings, like RedrivePolicy, you need to use the stand-alone **AWS::SNS::Subscription** resource (See [Subscription Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html)).

Since AWS::SNS::Subscription is stand-alone, you must include the TopicArn that the Subscription is bound to.  Also note that the RedrivePolicy is in Json format.

Here's a simple example of the Cloud Formation syntax from [Redrive Syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-configure-dead-letter-queue.html#configure-dead-letter-queue-aws-cloudformation):

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "mySubscription": {
      "Type" : "AWS::SNS::Subscription",
      "Properties" : {
        "Protocol": "sqs",
        "Endpoint": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:MyEndpoint",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:MyTopic",
        "RedrivePolicy": {
          "deadLetterTargetArn":
            "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:MyDeadLetterQueue"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't know how Ansible makes these translations.